# vue 3 親要素に v-if を指定して表示切替を行うことはできないのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
<div id="test" v-if="seen">
  <p>あいうえお</p>
  <button @click="remove">削除</button>
</div>
```

上記のHTMLでbutton をクリックすると、seen が false になり、全体が消えるvue を書いたのですが、効かないようです。

```
<div id="test">
  <p v-if="seen">あいうえお</p>
  <button @click="remove">削除</button>
</div>
```

次に、v-if を button の兄弟要素であるpに設定すると、その兄弟要素は消えて動作するようです。

したいことは、親要素であるdiv を削除したいのですが、不可能なのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

特に問題なく動作可能です
もしかすると `id="test"` で `mount`してませんか？ その場合 `v-if`を下位要素に指定してみてはどうでしょう

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="event-handling">
    <div v-if="type === 'A'">
      A
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="type === 'B'">
      B
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="type === 'C'">
      C
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      Not A/B/C
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="chg">変更</button>
    
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
const EventHandling = {
  data() {
    return {
      cnt: 0,
      type: 'A',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    chg() {
      if (++this.cnt > 2) this.cnt = 0
      this.type = 'ABC'[this.cnt]
      console.log(this.cnt)
      console.log(this.type)
    }
  }
}

Vue.createApp(EventHandling).mount('#event-handling')
</script>
</html>
```

---

#### 追記

`button` 要素を `div`の下位に配置しても動作可能です

```
    <div v-if="type === 'A'">
      A
      <button v-on:click="chg">変更</button>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="type === 'B'">
      B
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="type === 'C'">
      C
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      Not A/B/C
    </div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。

まず、v-if を子要素に指定するということですが、最上位のdiv の下にdiv を追加してそこに v-if を記述しました。

<div id="test">
<div v-if="seen">
  <p>あいうえお</p>
  <button @click="remove">削除</button>
</div>
</div>

しかし、これではうまくいきませんでした。

また、試していただいた例ですが、@click と v-if が指定されている要素が兄弟関係にあるようです。v-if が親要素にあると動作しないことを問題にしています。

Comment: 特に問題なく動きますよ

Comment: ありがとうございます。もう一度試したところ、動きました。

Comment: こちらのサービスはベストアンサー機能など無いのでしょうか？

Comment: ベストアンサーはないけどそれっぽいのはあります。
[質問にあたって](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) 内の https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers とか, [meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/) の [回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/) が参考になるかもです。